# IF condition with AJAX response or AJAX response.response.Text is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a web page which displays an alert as soon as somebody inserts a new tuple in a database table using the same `'mesa'` column that I sent in my AJAX request, so for that purpose I created a Javascript Timer in which I am constantly sending AJAX requests to check if there is a new tuple in my database table and so far the timed AJAX request are working, but when I want to condition the response with an `if` to see if the value of it equals to a certain value, it just completely skips it, so I am unable to display alerts even if the values that the AJAX response requests are throwing are right, so I was wondering what I could be doing wrong, I have been analyzing the code for over 2 hours and I don't seem to find the error, I even displayed alerts to verify that the `response` is equal to 0 or 1 which showed up that they do display them right, and I used `response.responseText` too , any help would he highly appreciated, thank you so much.

This is my Javascript file

```
var Solicitud_Comandas = [];


for (var k = 1; k <= 15; k++) {
      Solicitud_Comandas[k] = SolicitudComanda(k);

      if(!sessionStorage.getItem("rm"+k))
      {
            sessionStorage.setItem("rm"+k,false);
      }
}

function SolicitudComanda(k)
{
      return function() {
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Consultar_Comandas_Pendientes.php",
            data: {mesa : k},
            complete: function (response, TextStatus)
            { 
                  MensajeAlerta(response,k);
      },
      fail: function (resultado,TextStatus)
      {
            alert("it didn't work because... " + resultado+ " " +TextStatus);
      }
});
});
}
}

function MensajeAlerta(response,m)
{


            if(response == 0 )
            {
                  sessionStorage.removeItem("rm"+m);
                  sessionStorage.setItem("rm"+m,false);
            }
            else if (response == 1)
            {
                  if(sessionStorage.getItem("rm"+m) == "false")
                  {
                        alert("Hay una comanda pendiente en la mesa "+m);
                        sessionStorage.removeItem("rm"+m);
                        sessionStorage.setItem("rm"+m, true);
                  } 
            }
}

Temporizador= setInterval(SolicitudDeComanda,2500);

function SolicitudDeComanda()
{ 

      $(document).ready(function(){

            for (var l =1; l<= 15; l++) {
                  Solicitud_Comandas[l]();   
            };

      });

}
```

And this is the Consultar_Comandas_Pendientes.php

```
    <?php 
    require "Conexion.php";
    $NumeroMesa = $_POST["mesa"];
    $Platillos = 0;
    $filas = false;
    $SelectionRows = "SELECT * FROM comandapendiente WHERE mesa = '$NumeroMesa'";
    $rows = mysqli_query($con,$SelectionRows);
    while($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($rows))
    {   

        if(isset($reg["id"]))
        {
            $filas = true;
            $Platillos++;
        }
    }


    if ($filas == true)
    {

        echo true;
    }
    else
    {
        echo false;
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

As you can see, if there is a new tuple, the AJAX response is going to be equal to either `true` or `false` which is what I question on the `if` statements in the Javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue you have is caused by using the `$.ajax({ ... complete:` property and assuming the first argument to the callback is your data. But it is not, it is the request object (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). Use `success:` instead of `complete:` and then you get the data as first argument to your callback function.

The second issue you have is caused by the PHP line:

```
echo false;
```

This does not echo anything, because in PHP when `false` needs to be converted to string, it becomes the empty string, unlike in other languages, where it becomes "0" or "false".

So you should better echo literal strings in PHP, like:

```
echo "1";
```

and

```
echo "0";
```

Also, make sure PHP does not output anything else than just that 0 or 1. Specifically check that there are no blanks, tabs, empty lines... etc, before the  `<?php` tag or after the `?>` tag. If you have several such opening and closing tags, try to join them into one PHP block.

For the same reason, make sure to save your PHP in UTF-8 ***without BOM***. The Byte Order Mark is a three character sequence that is sometimes saved at the start of a file, in order to declare the character encoding as UTF-8. But this sequence would then also be part of the response. Most editors have an option to save with or without BOM.

#### Some remarks on your code

It is a bit strange to see `$(document).ready(...)` inside other functions. Although this works fine, it is not usually done this way. Normally there is no reason to have it inside another function. All is OK, if you use it once, at this position only:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Temporizador= setInterval(SolicitudDeComanda,2500);
});
```

I would write `false` as a string when writing to local storage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("rm"+k, "false");
```

It works fine without the quotes, but you then rely on the fact that JavaScript converts it to that string. I believe your code looks better with `"false"` written as a string explicitly.

Also, it seems unnecessary to call `removeItem()` if you are doing a `setItem()` right after it. `setItem()` overwrites any existing value with the same key.

In your tests on the response data, it would make more sense to do string comparisons, since the data returned by PHP will be string. So like:

```
if(response == "0")
```

... and add an `else` to catch any unexpected value (other than "0" or "1") so you are made aware of it (via alert or something).

If you have trouble with some unexpected characters preceding the value 0 or 1, and you can't get rid of those by removing the BOM and any white space in your PHP file, then there is a work-around by relaxing your test like this:

```
if (response.indexOf('0') !== -1)
```

It is also better to specify the `dataType: 'text'` option in your ajax call, so not to leave that to jQuery to guess.

Comment: I followed your advice and still the `if` statements don't work, yet if I use an  `alert` to display the `result` it displays 1 or 0, I just don't understand, could it be the encoding of the response that differs from the one in my HTML/JS file?

Comment: As the response data is a string, try doing your `if` as `if (reponse == "0")` to use string comparison. Same for `"1"`. Also put an `else` at the end to catch any other value than 0 or 1, and do an alert of that value.

Comment: Found another issue: use `success:` instead of `complete:` in your ajax options.

Comment: I am following your recommendations, and yeah there is something weird with the value of `response`, because it just doesn't print out `0` or `1`, it prints some wierd characters that my browser can't display, and then afterwards it prints the `0` or `1`, and both `success:` and `complete:` work fine in my ajax options.

Comment: Please refer to documentation. The arguments provided by `complete` are not the same. `complete` provides the request object as first argument to the callback. You really must use `success:` to get the response. It may also help to put the `dataType : 'text'` option in your ajax call. It defines the data type of the expected response.

Comment: I see, you are right  by using `success:` I do get the response, but that doesn't solve the problem that I have which is that the `if` statement doesn't work with the AJAX response to display the alerts and I already corrected my `if` in this manner `if (response=="0")`.

Comment: Can you be more specific: did you add an `else` to catch any other response value and alert it? What is the value of response?

Comment: I did, and I told you that the alert displays some wierd characters that my browser can't decode, and inmediately afterwards it displays either `0` or `1`, that's why I suggested that it might have something to do with the encoding of the JS/PHP file.

Comment: OK, in that case you need to check the PHP part: are there any blank lines or tabs or spaces before `<?php` or after `?>`? Then remove all that. There should be nothing else that PHP outputs. You can also do a more relaxed check in JavaScript: `if (response.indexOf('0') !== -1)` ... etc.

Comment: I wish I could show you the response output that my alert displays, I verified that there weren't any blank lines or tabs or spaces before the PHP tags and still it's useless, the if statements don't work in. It's just the data that the PHP throws back  it's not the pure `0` or `1`, there is something more that the `echo` sends, I will do some more tests to see if I can find the solution, so far thank you for your concern. The alert displays some square-like characters.

Comment: Another thing: verify that you save your PHP file as UTF-8 ***without BOM***. It might be that the strange characters you see are the Byte Order Mark (BOM). This you could easily solve by saving your PHP file without it. Most editors have such options.

Comment: Sublime Text allows you to save it with UTF-8 encoding, but it isn't specific in whether this means that it is without BOM. Well I saved as UTF-8 and the numbers of strange characters reduced, now instead of 4-5 of them there is just one and the value of the response which is either 1 or 0.

Comment: If you want to take the trouble, install notepad++, which will show you whether there is a BOM, and gives the option to save with or without it. However, you could ignore all this and do a more relaxed test in JavaScript as I suggested above: `if (response.indexOf('0') !== -1) ` ... etc. Did you try that?

Comment: You could also get more info and alert the character codes of the first few funny characters you get in the response, using `alert(response.charCodeAt(0) + ' ' + response.charCodeAt(1) + ' ' + response.charCodeAt(2));` Then research a bit more about BOM and see if these character codes have anything to do with it.

Comment: God bless you!! that `if (response.indexOf('0') !== -1) ` worked perfectly!, thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. It was time for me to go to bed, so this comes at the right time :-)

Comment: Yeah sorry for keeping you busy when you posted the answer early on, my bad.